# How to extract values for nested tag in an XML with namespaces?

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml-parsing

I'm parsing and XML using JQuery. Here you are a sample ...

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<wfs:FeatureCollection
 xmlns:ms="http://mapserver.gis.umn.edu/mapserver"
 xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"
 xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
 xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.0.0/WFS-basic.xsd 
                   http://mapserver.gis.umn.edu/mapserver http://wms.pcn.minambiente.it/ogc?map=/ms_ogc/wfs/Numeri_Civici_2012.map&amp;SERVICE=WFS&amp;VERSION=1.0.0&amp;REQUEST=DescribeFeatureType&amp;TYPENAME=IN.NUMERICIVICI.2012&amp;OUTPUTFORMAT=XMLSCHEMA">
  <gml:boundedBy>
    <gml:Box srsName="EPSG:4326">
        <gml:coordinates>7.700007,44.802147 7.749396,44.849996</gml:coordinates>
    </gml:Box>
  </gml:boundedBy>
<gml:featureMember>
  <ms:IN.NUMERICIVICI.2012 fid="IN.NUMERICIVICI.2012.2728384">
    <gml:boundedBy>
        <gml:Box srsName="EPSG:4326">
            <gml:coordinates>7.735138,44.810267 7.735138,44.810267</gml:coordinates>
        </gml:Box>
    </gml:boundedBy>
    <ms:boundary>
    <gml:Point srsName="EPSG:4326">
      <gml:coordinates>7.735138,44.810267</gml:coordinates>
    </gml:Point>
    </ms:boundary>
    <ms:id>13800026457291</ms:id>
    <ms:nome>Borgata Tetti Sotto</ms:nome>
    <ms:civico>16</ms:civico>
    <ms:istat>01004041</ms:istat>
    <ms:cap>12030</ms:cap>
    <ms:comune>CARAMAGNA PIEMONTE</ms:comune>
    <ms:nome_ted> </ms:nome_ted>
    <ms:provincia>CUNEO</ms:provincia>
    <ms:regione>PIEMONTE</ms:regione>
  </ms:IN.NUMERICIVICI.2012>
</gml:featureMember>
<gml:featureMember>
  <ms:IN.NUMERICIVICI.2012 fid="IN.NUMERICIVICI.2012.2736621">
    <gml:boundedBy>
        <gml:Box srsName="EPSG:4326">
            <gml:coordinates>7.735397,44.812403 7.735397,44.812403</gml:coordinates>
        </gml:Box>
    </gml:boundedBy>
    <ms:boundary>
    <gml:Point srsName="EPSG:4326">
      <gml:coordinates>7.735397,44.812403</gml:coordinates>
    </gml:Point>
    </ms:boundary>
    <ms:id>13800026457290</ms:id>
    <ms:nome>Borgata Tetti Sotto</ms:nome>
    <ms:civico>25</ms:civico>
    <ms:istat>01004041</ms:istat>
    <ms:cap>12030</ms:cap>
    <ms:comune>CARAMAGNA PIEMONTE</ms:comune>
    <ms:nome_ted> </ms:nome_ted>
    <ms:provincia>CUNEO</ms:provincia>
    <ms:regione>PIEMONTE</ms:regione>
  </ms:IN.NUMERICIVICI.2012>
</gml:featureMember>
```

I'm using this notation to extract tag values

```
$this.find('ms\\:nome, nome').text()
```

and all works fine.

I don't know how to extract values for the tag  **coordinates** that are nested under **Point** tag

```
    <gml:Point srsName="EPSG:4326">
      <gml:coordinates>7.735397,44.812403</gml:coordinates>
    </gml:Point>
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you very much!!

Cesare

Answer (score 0):

Would doing something like this work?

```
 $xml.find('gml:Point').each(function () {
     $this.find('gml:coordinates').text()
 });
```

then you can insert that data into a variable or show it in a table

Answer (score 0):

I've solved in this manner ...

```
$this.find('gml\\:Point, Point').find('gml\\:coordinates, coordinates').text()
```

It's working now